# Unable to click into form fields in WP plugin Formidable?

Tags: html, wordpress, forms

Here is the site with the issue: http://sites.udel.edu/materials-characterization/sponsorships/ .

I used the Formidable plugin on Wordpress to create this form and used the shortcode to put it on to my page, however, I am unable to click into the fields and fill out my information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer: use this css:

```
#post-146 {
    position: initial !important;
}
```

Or remove position:relative for #post-146

Hope that help!

Comment: thank you! I can now type into the fields. Is there a way, however, to move an initial positioned div like a relative one? (i.e. setting it with a negative top position to move it upward).

I attempted to do so with no success. I'm not sure if it's just what I'm doing, or if it's not possible.